# find the radius of convergence?

Tags: power-series

Determine the radius of convergence of the following  power series.

$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{a_n}(x-2017)^n\: \text{ with }\: a_n = \begin{cases} 1/2\:\text{ if  $n$  is even} \\ 1/3\:\text{ if  $n$ is odd} \end{cases}
\tag{1}\label{1}
$$

As far as I know.... to find the radius of convergence it must be true that 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right| < 1\tag{2}\label{2}
$$

But now I'm  stuck here  ... assuming that \eqref{2} holds, how  can I find the radius  of convergence?

Comment: Should be $\lim_{n\to\infty}|a_{n}/a_{n+1}|$. If this limit exists then it's the radius of convergence. But this is not the case for this series, thus you need to find another way to determine the radius of convergence.

Comment: i can 't  able to find the another  way .. can  u help  me ??@FrankLu

Comment: You may apply the Cauchy-Hadamard theorem, the radius of convergence is given by $$R=\frac{1}{\limsup_{n\to\infty}|a_n|^{\frac{1}{n}}}.$$In this case $R=1$.

Comment: thanks  and pliz see my answer @FrankLu..as  i have  written the answer.....is  it correct or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frank Lu has already answered almost comprehensively in the comments to this question: however I think it is a nice idea to precise some points. The standard way of calculating the radius of convergence of a power series is perhaps by using the *Cauchy-Hadamard* formula ([1], remark 5.2, p. 517)

$$
R=\left(\limsup_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{|a_n|}\right)^{-1}\tag{I}\label{I}
$$

Due to the properties of $\limsup$, the value of $R$ calculated by formula \eqref{I} *always exists*.

The formula for $R$ involving the inverse limit quotient as calculated for the ratio convergence test for the series $\sum a_n$, i.e.

$$
R=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|a_n|}{|a_{n+1}|}\tag{II}\label{II}
$$

works only if the ratio ${|a_n|}/{|a_{n+1}|}$ converges ([1], theorem 5.4, p. 518), and in this case obviously gives the same value as calculated by \eqref{I}. In the question posed by the OP, limit \eqref{II} does not exists since the sequence is oscillating, therefore the correct answer should be calculated only by formula \eqref{I}, i.e.
$$
R=\left(\limsup_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{|a_n|}\right)^{-1}=1
$$

[1] Emanuel Fisher (1983), "Intermediate Real Analysis", Springer Verlag.

Comment: Thanks @Daniele...but  pliz  edits  ur answer,,

Comment: @Michael. Thanks for accepting my answer: I am not able to see why there are problems in its screen rendering. I already edited it two times without succeeding in solving the issue: in the edit screen I correctly see all formulas, but when I save it, the first two show up only as LaTEX/MathML code. Perhaps some sys admin could help us.

Comment: @Michael: I succede in correcting the strange behavior. Apparently the tags and labels I placed to identify equations interact with the ones I added when I edited the text of your question.

Answer (score 0):

The series can be decomposed in two convergent parts,

$$\frac12\sum_{n=0}^\infty(x-2017)^{2n}+\frac13\sum_{n=0}^\infty(x-2017)^{2n+1}$$

and both have radius of convergence $1$. For $x=2016$ and $x=2018$, they diverge and so does the sum (there is no cancellation).

Comment: @ Yves   im not getting  ...as both  have  radius  of convergence  1  that  mean  Radius  of  convergence  of given series  must be 1+1 =2

Comment: @Michael: what's your rationale for summing the radii of convergence ?  (other than random guess...)